# How to get Rails to render html_safe text as live links?

Tags: html, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I built a CSV uploader to populate a cms I'm coding from scratch -- Rails 3.2.12.  One of the columns was originally raw html -- that's uploaded and what is displaying on the table.

```
<a href="http://g.co/maps/phb35">Map</a>
```

This column is a "Map" column where I need a live link to Google Maps.  I cannot get this column to render as anything but text.  Did twitter-bootstrap-rails mess something up?  I've tried

```
@raw
```

and using

```
html_safe
```

a couple different ways and messing with a variety of helpers (helpers file is currently empty); nothing is working.  Here are a couple attempts from file = show.html.erb

```
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:map) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= raw @meeting.map.html_safe %></dd>

<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:map) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @meeting.map %></dd>
```

So maybe there's a gem that works?  (Ha!) Rinku seemed promising, but was a bust. I have over 580 records in this CMS and I don't want to manually edit each one, even if it means stripping out the

part.  Thanks!

Here's the github:  https://github.com/indie/sccaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out!  There's no need for helpers, raw(@anything) or messing with sanitized HTML.  I used grep to change the link format of the DB data to straight `http://` links, and in the `<TD>` used: `<%= link_to meeting.map, url_for(meeting.map), target: "_blank" %>`  ... see the lovely results here:  https://github.com/indie/aasj

Answer (score 0):

Is your data stored in the database as escaped html?

Try:

`<%= raw CGI.unescapeHTML(@meeting.map) %>`